# ExtJS 4 and grid and speed

Tags: extjs

I have very simple grid (30 lines and 20 columns) with some numbers. And I have to make a lot of operations on this data in the runtime. I mean - user enter data to the cell and program check lines, columns, some single cells and results write to some cells in this grid.

I found that reading is quite good but writing is horrible slow, even in such a small grid.

I found also, that when I set pair:
`suspendLayouts()` and `resumeLayouts(true)`

before and after block of grid operations speed is much better. But in this grid I use `celledit` plugin and problem with speed is the same.

Could you suggest me some rules how to write such a code to make it max speedy?

Comment: don't access dom much. that will improve overall performance. are you using 10k+ data otherwise, grid will be faster always

Comment: try to use Ext.fly in necessary places. will also improve the performance